# Function to output function name

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, template-haskell

Is it possible in Haskell to implement a function which returns its own function name?

A possible type could be `(a -> b) -> String`.

Comment: No. A function of type `(a -> b) -> String` can't inspect its argument (beyond `seq`ing it or applying it to bottom) due to its polymorphic type. Thus it has no means to identify its argument.

Comment: If a function returns *its own* function name, wouldn't the type be `() -> String` (and the implementation rather trivial)?

Comment: Most functions in Haskell don't even have names. Something that could exist would be a function that shows the type of an expression, although I doubt that would be very useful.

Comment: If you had a function like that, what would you use it for? There's probably a simpler solution to your problem.

Comment: In addition to what Daniel Fischer said, this would violate equational reasoning: `let f = id in findName f` would presumably be intended to produce `"f"`, but `findName id` would presumably be intended to produce `"id"`.  This is all related to the fact that functions simply don't have names; variables can be in scope which have function type, but that's it.

Comment: I found this question because I was looking for a way to trace the execution of certain functions without having to change each function. Not sure what the Haskelly way to do that is but I was looking for some equivalent to the way log4j uses reflection to give class execution context when logging.

Answer (score 18):

You want a function that takes a function argument, and returns the definition site variable name that corresponds to the name of that function?

This isn't possibly without meta-programming, which is usually a sign you're doing something wrong :).
But assuming you're not, one way to achieve something in the right direction is via [Template Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell), which can get at unique names (how the compiler names things). E.g.

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> :set -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> let f x y = x + y
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> $( stringE . show =<< reify 'f )

     "VarI f_1627394057
                (ForallT [PlainTV a_1627394063]
                         [ClassP GHC.Num.Num [VarT a_1627394063]]
                              (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a_1627394063)) 
                                    (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a_1627394063)) 
                                         (VarT a_1627394063)))) 
                         Nothing (Fixity 9 InfixL)"
```

And now we know a lot about the variable. So you can play games by passing a Name to the function (via 'f) rather than f itself.

You are certainly in the world of reflection and meta-programming though, so it would help to know more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify something mentioned in dons' post: no functions have names in Haskell. There are bindings which may bind functions, but if I had such a function (call it `getName`) as you seek then what would you expect this to return:

```
let f x = x
    g   = f
    h   = f
in  getName g == getName h
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you need it for, but maybe a simplistic solution suffices? Like so:

```
data NamedFunction a b = NamedFunction { 
    name :: String,
    apply :: a -> b
}

timesTwo :: NamedFunction Int Int
timesTwo = NamedFunction "timesTwo" (\x -> 2 * x)
```

which you can use as follows:

```
ghci> timesTwo `apply` 7
14
ghci> name timesTwo
"timesTwo"
```

You can then write your own version of `(.)`:

```
-- contrast (.)  ::    (b -> c) ->          (a -> b) ->         (a -> c)
compose :: NamedFunction b c -> NamedFunction a b -> NamedFunction a c
compose (NamedFunction n1 f1) (NamedFunction n2 f2) = 
     NamedFunction (n1++ " . " ++ n2) (f1 . f2)
```

In ghci:

```
ghci> let f = timesTwo `compose` timesTwo in (f `apply` 7, name f) 
(28,"timesTwo . timesTwo")
```

You'll have to reimplement your own versions of `map`, `filter` and so on, and you're bound to run into other problems later, but maybe this is all you need...

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? This function returns its own function name.

```
Prelude> let myNameIs::(a->b) -> String; myNameIs f = "myNameIs"
Prelude> :type myNameIs
myNameIs :: (a -> b) -> String
Prelude> myNameIs myNameIs
"myNameIs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your source code with CPP. In CPP

```
#define _NAMEOF(name) #name
```

defines a macro, `_NAMEOF`, for stringifying text (including surrounding it with programmer's quotation marks). You can then use it as follows:

```
head [] = error $ _NAMEOF(head) ++ ": empty list!"
```

which CPP should translate into a valid Haskell source code line:

```
head [] = error $ "head" ++ ": empty list!"
```